# Can I rename a class and all its occurences/references in VS code?

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code

I would like to rename a class that is a part of a huge project. I have IntelliSense, IntelliPhense and all related installed.

The project is Laravel, although there's a ton of custom code as well.

Is there a suggested extension or built-in way to do that, because I couldn't find any?

Comment: Right click -> Rename (or press F2)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the general search and replace on `vscode` by using `ctrl + shift + F` and you can skip (close) whichever you think its not part of what you wish to replace.

[image]

Here the total occurrence of `TransactionController` 31 and found in 5 files, you can close any file you don't want to replace the name.